# Firebase Analytics Continuously Tracks UINavigationController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, firebase, firebase-analytics

I'm transitioning from Google Analytics to Firebase Analytics.  Unlike Google Analytics, Firebase automatically tracks screen views, which is great!  But, instead of tracking the screen, it continuously attempts to track the UINavigationController.  I get the following error log twice every time I navigate to a different view controller.

> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS031006] View controller already
>   tracked. Class, ID: UINavigationController, -1770652405567491888

Is there some configuration required when you have a navigation controller?  How do I get automatic screen tracking working in this scenario?

**UPDATE:** I haven't found a solution to this yet, but I at least found the cause of the problem.  It looks like Firebase doesn't understand your view controller hierarchy if your initial view controller is a Tab Bar Controller.  My initial view controller in my main story board is a Tab Bar Controller.  If I take this out, I get good screen tracking reporting from my app.

**UPDATE:**  It looks like I've found an OK solution to this, but I'm still wondering if someone has a better idea.  Since Firebase sees all of the view controllers under my Tab Bar Controller as the same UINavigationController, I can call setScreenName manually in viewDidAppear for all of them.

```
Analytics.setScreenName(screenName, screenClass: screenClass)
```

This is OK because it's not any worse than Google Analyics, but it's not ideal because the system still tries to track the UINavigationController twice for every view controller and I'm also not getting the benefit of automatic screen tracking.  I looked into trying to remove the Tab Bar Controller from Firebase as some folks seem to have done, but it looks like those methods have been removed from the current (v4.0.0) version of the Firebase SDK.

Comment: Did you ever find a better fix for this? The screen view analytics are useless because this. I can't find any one else talking about this issue either.

Answer (score 0):

Screen is automatically tracked in Google Analytics for Firebase. You can see it in the user engagement card in the Main dashboard. This has been introduced in [Firebase Version 3.8.0](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios) for iOS. More in [track screen](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/screenviews) doc. Quoting from the doc:

*Events that occur on these screens are automatically tagged with the parameter firebase_screen_class (for example, menuViewController or MenuActivity) and a generated firebase_screen_id. If your app uses a distinct UIViewController or Activity for each screen, **Analytics can automatically track every screen transition and generate a report of user engagement broken down by screen.***

However, you can also track screens [manually](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/screenviews#manually_track_screens) using the setCurrentScreen() method. The details on this screen should be available in the user engagement card when you select the *ScreenName* from the dropdown, all the screens manually tracked in the code should be displayed there with the breakdown of duration on average.

Please note that the setScreenName is not an event, it is rather an event parameter that goes with the event that is tracked in the *logEvent()* method call.

Comment: This is all useful and correct information, but it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Is there also a way to turn off all automatic analytics events? Such as "first_open", "session_start", etc... we have our own system and do not want the additional noise. Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at the "disable analytics collection" doc firebase.google.com/support/guides/disable-analytics